# AWS AppSync Update Schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS AppSync web console, I created a new API from scratch.

I created a new resource like this:

```
type ToDo {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}
```

After AWS AppSync created the DynamoDB table and Schema, what can I do if I want to update the schema and add a new field?

```
type ToDo {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  completed: Boolean
}
```

I know AWS Amplify has a command `amplify api gql-compile` and then `amplify push` and it will update the schema and the DynamoDB tables.

Is there a way to do this from the AWS AppSync [web console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/appsync/)?

Comment: I believe you want to simply edit and save in web console

Comment: Correct, I want to simply edit, save and generate the new mutations, queries and update the database table from the web.

Comment: @AbeEstrada have you found solution?

Comment: @atlascoder not yet, but maybe the new [Admin](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-amplify-admin-ui-helps-you-develop-app-backends-no-cloud-experience-required/) is what I need, but I need to take a look

Comment: @AbeEstrada thanks, the Admin is new feature for me

Answer (score 3):

If you used the AWS AppSync Console wizard to create this.  You will need to do the following:

```
type ToDo {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    completed: Boolean # add here
}

input UpdateToDoInput {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    completed: Boolean # add here
}

input CreateToDoInput {
    title: String
    completed: Boolean # add here
}

input TableToDoFilterInput {
    id: TableIDFilterInput
    title: TableStringFilterInput
    completed: Boolean # add here
}
```

Now their should be an orange button "Save Schema" in the upper right hand corner of the console.  If you press that it will save your new schema and you can run some new queries against your AWS AppSync API.

Go to the query window and add completed into your mutation and listToDos selection sets.

```
# Click the orange "Play" button and select the createToDo
# mutation to create an object in DynamoDB.
# If you see an error that starts with "Unable to assume role",
# wait a moment and try again.
mutation createToDo($createtodoinput: CreateToDoInput!) {
  createToDo(input: $createtodoinput) {
    id
    title
    completed
  }
}


# After running createToDo, try running the listToDos query.
query listToDos {
  listToDos {
    items {
      id
      title
      completed
    }
  }
}
```

Update your query variables to include a value for completed

```
{
  "createtodoinput": {
    "title": "Hello, world!",
    "completed":true
  }
}
```

That should be all you need to do for a simple attribute.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that's why I want to avoid, manually doing all the changes, would love to have a "Update Resources" (`amplify api gql-compile && amplify push`) button on the web, that can keep track of the mutations and queries and I can just focus on the schema, because your explanation works on simple updates.